# Rails 4 - Returning empty value in each statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, materialize

In my application I'm rendering comment part with each statement but getting an unusual response in it. An empty comment is always been there. I'm using Rails 4 with materialize css. This is how it [looks](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1422159/fbabde9acca44d7813726991a087eb40) like.

Here is my code

```
  <div class="s12 m7 l8 col">
    <ul class="collection with-header">

      <li class="collection-header">
        <h5>Comment's for you</h5>
      </li>

      <% @student.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <li class="collection-item">
        <!-- Content in single row -->
        <div>

          <%= comment.content %>

          <% if comment.user_id == current_user.id || current_user.try(:admin?) %>
          <%= link_to [comment.student, comment], method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: "secondary-content" do %>
          <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
          <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: An empty comment is always been there..  means you get empty comments  in view.. right..??

Comment: Yes, it is in view (show.html.erb file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you don't want to show empty comments?

which would be produced with this code:

```
  <li class="collection-header">
    <h5>Comments for you</h5>
  </li>

  <% @student.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <% if comment.content.present? %>
      <li class="collection-item">
        <!-- Content in single row -->
        <div>

          <%= comment.content %>

          <% if comment.user_id == current_user.id || current_user.try(:admin?) %>
            <%= link_to [comment.student, comment], method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: "secondary-content" do %>
            <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I think a better way would be to validate the comments before saving them.
(see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of)

Comment: And that's awesome, works like a charm. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the condition and prevent empty comments

```
 if !comment.content.empty?
    comment.content
 end
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This does nothing. This will only print the comment content if it's not empty, but I think what he want, that the row is not there if the comment is empty.

Comment: What's that `different way`? I just say that this solution does not change anything :)

Comment: @RaVeN  I expalin in simple way.. where put condition is up to developer. if it dont want whole row than he need to put condition before the div.  it should depend on developer how to use code..

Answer (score 0):

As [RaVeN mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38563324/2662537), your issue is probably lack of validation. You (*probably*) have a Comment record with empty content in your database.

In order to validate your model, please look-up the documentation, it's well written: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

An example would be:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

You may also want to add some minimum / maximum text length, in that case you can pass `length` Hash as another validation:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 140 }
end
```